# update some values in a Laravel session

Tags: laravel, session

I have two projects where I need to update some values in my session. It works in my other project, so I used the same code in my new project ( same laravel version ). Now it won't work anymore and I don't know why. I don't get any error message, like if everything is working correctly, but it doesn't.

Here is some dummy data of how an item in my session looks like:

```
articleNr: "16xxxxxx"
pictureUrl: "http://blablablabla...."
title: 'chocolate' 
count: 7 // thats the amount - So I want 7x chocolate
```

Code:

```
$product_cartData = $request['product_data'];  // In product data is the articlenumber and the amount I want to update ( like if I want to buy 5x this item ) 
$all_products = $request->session()->get('products');
foreach ($product_cartData as $data) {
    foreach ($all_products as $key => $sProduct) {
        if ($sProduct['articleNr'] == $data['id']) {
            $sProduct['count'] = (int)$data['quantitie'];
        }
        // return $sProduct; <--- this returns the item with the updated quantitie 
    }
}
return session('products', $all_products); // <--- but here the quantitie isn't updated anymore
```

Does someone know why? Thats exactly how I did it in my other project and its working fine.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: try your foreach like `foreach ($all_products as $key => &$sProduct)`

Comment: that haven't changed a thing :/

Answer (score 1):

No sure why you want to return session.

To store date to a session try

```
session(['key' => 'value']); 

// Via a request instance...
 $request->session()->put('key', 'value');
```

this would be a really good place to start https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session

Comment: I tried the put method of course but this haven't worked for me

Comment: The problem is not in saving the data in the session, but rather modifying the `$allProducts` array.

Comment: well and how do I save the data correctly? I understand that I've only changing the variable, not the session itself. But how do I save my changes? Put haven't worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I found that on some projects the session persistence wasn't working as expected and that each time I wanted to update a session variable it was vital to also call Session::save().

```
\Session::put("session_variable_name","abc");
\Session::save();
```